# Properly installing and using Nuitka within Anaconda, " No module named 'nuitka.__main__' "

Tags: command-line, python, anaconda, libraries, virtualenv

I'm trying to use Nuitka within the Anaconda Prompt.

Nuitka has been installed through conda: `conda install -c conda-forge nuitka`

See documentation here: https://nuitka.net/doc/user-manual.html#tutorial-setup-and-build-on-windows

Python is not installed anywhere on the computer except under Anaconda.

I try `nuitka` and get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\nuitka-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nuitka.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nuitka.__main__'
```

`nuitka.exe` is the file being called here, and it appears to call `nuitka-script.py`. `nuitka-script.py` fails to import the `__main__.py` file.

I can also type `python -m nuitka --version` with the output

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe: No module named nuitka.__main__; 'nuitka' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Something similar to this has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967732/error-nuitka-is-a-package-and-cannot-be-directly-executed-when-trying-to-execu

There is no nuitka.bat file located in Scripts, or anywhere that I have identified.

The python scripts for nuitka can be found at `anaconda3\pkgs\nuitka-0.6.5-py_0\site-packages\nuitka`, where there is a `__main__.py` file.

What can I do from here so that I can conveniently call nuitka within the Anaconda Prompt? For example, `python -m nuitka --follow-imports awesome.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tried `conda install --force-reinstall -c conda-forge nuitka`.
That solved the problem.